# Syntax error in MS Project custom field formula

Tags: ms-project

I want to write a custom field formula in MS Project but for every variation it gives syntax error for the text in `""`, so for example in the example below for "Very low"

```
IIf([Text5] < 6, "Very low", IIf([Text5] >= 6 And [Text5] <= 14, "Medium", IIf([Text5] > 14, "Very high", "No risk")))
```

Comment: That is a valid formula for a text field. Verify the field with this formula is a text field. If still having problems, add a screenshot or two to your question.

Comment: Is it possible that your default delimiter is a semicolon instead of a comma?

Answer (score 0):

You are performing arithmetic on text data (`[Text5]`). I suggest you use a Number custom field in place of `[Text5]` and your error should disappear.